# transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug error while running app on device

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I try to develop simple application with notifications using Firebase platform. I was receiving error `:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug` which I fixed by adding line `multiDexEnabled true` into  `build.gradle`.
After this edit I am getting error `:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug`
My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android 

    {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.jaroslavvystavel.noti"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 25
            multiDexEnabled true  // this line will solve this problem
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
            }
        }    
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
}
```

Build is without issue, the problem happens when I try to run the app on the connected phone. When I use AVD I receive message `App has stopped`..
I was developing the app according to this tutorial [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNF_yho6ook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apply plugin` for `google-services` must follow the dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is described in the documentation for the [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).